# Awarded bounty value is inconsistent

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, bounties

[My profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/444991/matt?tab=bounties) is saying I awarded **300** points for a bounty.

[image: +300 badge on profile page]

While [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2821232/code-profiling-in-the-windows-sidebar-environment) is saying that I awarded **350** points for the bounty.

[image: +350 badge on answer]

Comment: Was there already a 50 point bounty awarded to that answer?

Comment: @jonsca: If you check the revision of the question, it shows a single bounty of 350 awarded (http://stackoverflow.com/posts/2821232/revisions)

Comment: Yes, and the recipient has 350 on his profile.  Does the system allow for a bounty of 350 any more or is it just whole hundreds (I can't remember)?  That's the only thing I can think of.

Comment: Ah, balpha has cleared it up.  Just out of curiosity, how come this is coming to your attention now?

Comment: Ah, Figured it might have been something like that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*You* did indeed award 300 of your own reputation, so the number in your profile is correct.

The answerer, however, did indeed receive 350 reputation for this, because this bounty happend in May of 2010, which was before [the changes to the bounty system](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/improvements-to-bounty-system/). Back then, the system threw in an additional 50 rep to bounties (this is no longer the case).

So both values are correct.

Comment: Sounds good to me :)

Comment: Whoah, that's weird. Time fold/warp/paradox!